# Zip folders/ files according to business criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have a requirement where I need to zip each individual files or folders depending upon the creation date of files. So, if all files under a folder meets the business criteria I need to zip the folder, if it does not I need to zip the individual files. Also, if all the sibling folders meet the criteria I need to zip the parent folder instead of the child folder. 
[image: Dir Structure image]

So, for ex if I have the directory structure as in the diagram and let’s assume all files under folder 6 meets the criteria but not all files under folder 7 does not, then files which meet the criteria under folder 7 is zipped, but the whole folder 6 is zipped. In case if all files under folder 6, folder 7 and folder 3 meets the criteria then folder 3 is zipped, if contents under Folder 2 does not meet criteria. If contents under folder 2, folder 3 and folder 1 meets the criteria then folder 1 is zipped.

I can write an algorithm to zip the last level in the tree, but if I need to go up the tree and check the details of the parent folder and decide, I am not sure how to proceed on it.

Comment: What exactly is the question? D you have Problems to zip a folder? I would first traverse the file-tree than decide what to zip and than create the zip-files.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I am sorry if you did not understand the question. The issue is not with  zipping the folder or file. The issue is with zipping according to the business rule. Zipping the folder if all the files matches the business rule or zipping the individual files if all files does not match the rule. I have provided an example of the requirement in the question. Let me know what is not clear there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we would ask for the source code you have written so far, but if I understand correctly it is more the recursion idea than the code itself you are looking for, so here comes source code that explains the recursion idea.

There are other ways to do this, but this one is pretty straight forward. As I see this, you need to recurse twice, since the leafs may affect each other (first gather data bottom->top, then deliver data top->bottom).

I built a folder structure under c:/temp/zipper to test the code. Files starting with 'm' match the criteria. Hopefully the comments and the System.outs explain what is going on.

```
public class Zipper {

private static String NO_ZIP_MESSAGE = "";
// private static String NO_ZIP_MESSAGE = " (no zip)";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Zipper().go("C:/temp/zipper");
}

private void go(String startingFolderStr) {
    MyFile startingFolder = new MyFile(new File(startingFolderStr), false);
    boolean zipStartingFolder = recurse(startingFolder, "");
    System.out.println("------------------ " + zipStartingFolder);
    cleanup(startingFolder, "", false);
}

private boolean recurse(MyFile folder, String indent) {

    // Go through the folder structure top-down and check if individual files meet the criteria, and also update zip
    // flag for folders in "direct descendance".

    System.out.println(indent + folder.file.getName());
    boolean allSiblingsMeetCriteria = true;
    for (File f : folder.file.listFiles()) {
        MyFile mf = new MyFile(f, false);
        folder.siblings.add(mf);
        if (f.isFile()) {
            boolean meetsCriteria = f.getName().startsWith("m");
            mf.zip = !meetsCriteria;
            allSiblingsMeetCriteria = allSiblingsMeetCriteria && meetsCriteria;
            System.out.println(indent + "      " + f.getName() + (meetsCriteria ? "" : " --> ZIP"));
        } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
            allSiblingsMeetCriteria = recurse(mf, indent + "  ") && allSiblingsMeetCriteria;
        }
    }
    folder.zip = allSiblingsMeetCriteria;
    System.out.println(
            indent + "... " + folder.file.getName() + (allSiblingsMeetCriteria ? " --> ZIP" : NO_ZIP_MESSAGE));
    return allSiblingsMeetCriteria;
}

private void cleanup(MyFile folder, String indent, boolean parentIsZipped) {

    // If we come to a folder with zip=true, all its subfolders have zip=true and all its subfiles have zip=false.
    // Set parentIsZipped=true, and go thru and set all subfolders to zip=false (1). Ignore subfiles since they are
    // already ok.

    // If we come to a folder with zip=false (and we're not in a 'true flow' (comment above)), all subfiles should
    // have zip=true (2), but we leave subfolders as is

    System.out.println(indent + folder.file.getName() + (folder.zip ? " --> ZIP" : NO_ZIP_MESSAGE));
    parentIsZipped = parentIsZipped || folder.zip;
    for (MyFile mf : folder.siblings) {
        if (mf.file.isFile()) {
            if (!parentIsZipped) {
                mf.zip = true; // (2)
            }
            System.out.println(indent + "      " + mf.file.getName() + (mf.zip ? " --> ZIP" : NO_ZIP_MESSAGE));
        } else if (mf.file.isDirectory()) {
            if (parentIsZipped) {
                mf.zip = false; // (1)
            }
            cleanup(mf, indent + "  ", parentIsZipped);
        }
    }
}

private class MyFile {

    File file;
    boolean zip;
    List<MyFile> siblings;

    public MyFile(File file, boolean zip) {
        this.file = file;
        this.zip = zip;
        siblings = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your help.

Comment: No problem @gechu (also, feel free to also upvote my answer :) )